# Distance between particular points on two circles

Tags: geometry

Here's the set-up:

[image: 1]

Take three circles entered at $(-1,0),(0,0),(1,0)$ with radii $\sqrt 2$ and $1$.

Then pick $p$, any point on the right-hand circle. Reflect $p$ in the horizontal axis to get $-p$. Draw the line segment from $(0,0)$ to $-p$.

Then $q$ is the intersection of this segment with the left circle.

Prove that the distance between $p$ and $q$ is $2$.

I have proved this using complex analysis, but is there an intuitive way to do this using pure geometry?

Comment: What’s the point of having the middle circle?

Comment: @amd to confuse both the enemies and allies, but mostly the student.

Comment: It could be a hint...

Comment: I would just say it intuitively... since the centers of the circles are exactly 2 units away... all corresponding projections of an arc onto another arc, whose arc curvatures are identical, the distance will be the separation of the centers.

Answer (score 1):

A hint that might help. The following diagram will help with the hint:

[image]

ED=2 as well. Prove that AE is parallel to CD and that AB=EB (or BD=BC).
Hope this helps to get the geometry based solution:)

Answer (score 0):

Might the complex analysis itself be a form of two-dimensional geometry?  We can render complex numbers as vectors in the complex plane.  Addition is obvious.  Multiplication by a+bi corresponds to a linear transformation using the multiplier matrix

a b

-b a

Matrices having the above form are isomorphous with the complex numbers.